# Javascript Go To A URL If user input a specific number else go to another url

Tags: javascript, html, input

I want if user input on id `input-code` is only `1234abc`, then then he'll be redirected to Google. If he enter anything else, then he'll be redirected to Bing.

My HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Code" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Your Code'" maxlength="10" id="input-code">
<p><a href="#" class="btn" onclick="return btntest_onclick()">VERIFY NOW</a></p>
```

MY Javascript:

```
    if (document.getElementById('input-code').value == '1234'){
        function btntest_onclick(){
            window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
        }
        btntest_onclick()
    }else{
        function btntest_onclick(){
            window.location.href = "http://www.bing.com";
        }
        btntest_onclick()
    }
```

But with this code, when I go to my page, it instantly redirect me to Bing.

Comment: Your function declaration within the if and else blocks is weird.  This is happpening because the function is executing immediately as the page loads.

Comment: Never conditionally declare functions in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring the same function twice, so it is running the last defined version. And because your code is not in a function or bound to an event it runs on page load. Try this:

```
function btntest_onclick(){
    if (document.getElementById('input-code').value == '1234') {
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
    } else {
        window.location.href = "http://www.bing.com";
    }
};
```