# Multiple Text Values Pointing To One Link

Tags: javascript, arrays, url

I've used the answer to this question here: [Javascript Go To A URL If user input a specific number else go to another url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007267/javascript-go-to-a-url-if-user-input-a-specific-number-else-go-to-another-url)

To help me point to a link depending on what the value is. I now need to have multiple values pointing to the same link.

So for example, if the value is Afghanistan OR Armenia, then go to this link.

Searched through google cant seem to get it working. Any help or advice will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: use a `switch()` to determine which value is entered and based on that value, execute your block of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `switch` to determine the value and based on that, you can execute a block of code. Take a look at the code below or this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jorrex/o84bwcxb/) or just run the snippet below.

```js
$("#btnHit").click(function() {
  var value = $("#txtValue").val();
  if(value !== "" && value !== undefined)
  {
   switch(value.toLowerCase())
        {
         case "afghanistan":
            case "armenia":
               //window.location.href = "http://www.google.be";
                alert("Redirecting to Google!");
                break;
        
            case "belgium":
            case "france":
            case "england":
            case "germany":
               alert("Redirecting to Facebook!");
  //window.location.href = "http://www.facebook.com";
          break;
        
            default:
         //window.location.href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
                alert("Redirecting to www.stackoverflow.com");
        }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtValue"/>
<button id="btnHit">
Hit me!
</button>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much! Added +1